# Issue with String Manipulation in Powershell TrimEnd()

Tags: string, powershell

I have this PowerShell script that renames a file.  The following is part of the string manipulation code (not my actual code, just to show the issue):

```
$text="String1.txt"
$text
$text.trimend(".txt")
$date=Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
$text + $date
$newFile = $text.trimend(".txt") + "_" + $date + ".bak"
$newFile
$NewFile1 = $newFile.TrimEnd("_$date.bak") + ".bak"
$NewFile1
```

The result is:

```
String1.txt
String1
String1.txt20131104
String1_20131104.bak
String.bak
```

Why was the `1` at the end of `String1` removed as well? I am expecting the result to be `String1.bak`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trimend() method takes a character array (not string) argument, and will trim all of the characters in the array that appear at the end of the string.

I usually use the -replace operator for trimming off a string value:

```
$text="String1.txt"
$text 
$text = $text -replace '\.txt$',''
$text

String1.txt
String1
```

Answer (score 0):

Developing on the answer at [PowerShell to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168475/powershell-to-remove-text-from-a-string), I'm using these regex's to trim off an extension of unkown type with possible `.` elsewhere in the filename:

```
$imagefile="hi.there.jpg"
$imagefile
hi.there.jpg
$imagefile -replace '\.([^.]*)$', ''
hi.there
$imagefile -replace '([^.]*)$', ''
hi.there.
```