# Remove "OU=Domain Controller " in exported csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm able to export my Active Directory OU accounts in a CSV file but the problem is I get this output:

```
"Domain Controllers","OU=Domain Controllers,DC=testlab,DC=com"
```

I just want to have an output just like this:

```
"Domain Controllers","DC=testlab,DC=com"
```

Here is my script right now:

```
import-module activedirectory 
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * | select Name,@{l='DistinguishedName';e={($_.DistinguishedName)}} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\ADOrganizationalUnitsexport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Guessing you didn't even try researching this yourself, as you would have found  `Replace` does exactly what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168475/powershell-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want the first and 3rd option, you can use split and join like this:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * | 
Select Name,@{l='DistinguishedName';e={(($_.DistinguishedName -split ','))[0,2] -join ','}} | 
Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\ADOrganizationalUnitsexport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

be aware that it will not work in all cases, as sometimes you have more OU's before and after, so you must find the right way, it's just to give you a direction.

And, of course you can use replace and some other options, but you have to do some research and invest some effort to get the right results...