# How to bulk rename files in folder such that all characters BEFORE and including "_" is removed

Tags: powershell

I've been searching online for some help on this but can't seem to find the right answer.

Everything I've come across so far helps with renaming files in batch, but only such that the files are renamed by trimming all characters AFTER a special character (in my case it's "_"). I would actually like to know how to rename all files in a folder such that I trim all characters BEFORE (and including) the underscore.

Example: I have "AB CD_2019481-1" and want the name to be "2019481-1"

I would be open to using Powershell or CMD!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168475/powershell-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Comment: What is your plan if two files would produce the same name? "AB CD_2019481-1" and "EF GH_2019481-1"

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there is one and only one underscore in all of the file names, you can do a -split on the underscore character, then take the right side of the split.

```
$Filename = 'AB CD_2019481-1'
$NewFilename = ($Filename -split '_')[1]
```

The `-split '_'` splits the string into an array based on the delimiter, underscore. Then the `[1]` retrieves the 2nd element from the left, which should be the right-hand side of the filename.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you for your suggestion! I would definitely like to try it out. Do you perhaps know how to try this for a folder containing all of the files that I'd like to rename? (instead of typing out "$Filename = " for every file)

Comment: Hi raltmer, you would use the Get-ChildItem command, e.g.:

`$FolderPath = ...; Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath | ForEach-Object {     $Filename = $_.Name; ... }`

(`.Name` is for the filename only; use `.FullName` for the entire file path)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.  With the -whatif, it's harmless.  It should do what you ask.  If your filename has more than one underscore, it may not do what you want.  You can pipe get-item or get-childitem to it.

```
get-item 'AB CD_2019481-1' | 
  rename-item -newname { $_ -replace '.*_' } -whatif
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as they could be. Also, it is likely that this `-replace` regex will be, by default, greedy and take everything until the last, not the first, LOW LINE in the string.

Comment: @lit I added a description.