# powershell: remove characters in string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a list of files in this format NameSerie.S0E1.randomcharacters.mkv where i want to remove the randomcharacters to get NameSerie.S0E1.mkv

I have the following but for this i need to know the randomcharacters which sadly are random.

```
#rename files
Get-ChildItem $Location | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("[480p]","") }
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell to remove text from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168475/powershell-to-remove-text-from-a-string)

Comment: Please define (in the question) what is recognizable in your string rather than what is not. Presumably the extension is always `.mkv` (or not???), are the dots always on the same place? Is there always a `S#E#` format in front of the random characters? etc.

Comment: the .mkv is always there and the rest is always formated like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
(.*?)[^.]+\.([^.]+)$
```

And replace this with

```
$1$2
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CPY69G/1/).
Alternatively, you could split on the dot and glue the array back together programatically.

Comment: Yes, this is it!  Thanks for the link, I was looking for a website like this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#rename files
Get-ChildItem $Location | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Split(".")[0..1] -join ".$($_.Name.Split(".")[3])" }
```